# Почему результат в консоле разработчика хром отличается от результата в других консолях разработчика?

Tags: javascript

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. Уже не в первый раз заметила, что если перепроверять результаты в разных консолях то и результат будет разным. Ситуация повторяется и в случае с alert и console.log. Пример:
есть такой код: "const web = 'html';
alert('css', web, 'js');". При написании его в [этой онлайн-консоле](https://replit.com/) результат такой (*выведется всё написанное*)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я этот же код ввожу тут же в консоль хрома, то результат будет такой (*выведется только первое из написанного*): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему так происходит и какой из консолей доверять.

апд. ошибка была в том, что я не разобралась как правильно работать с console.log() в браузере.

Comment: Аlert принимает один аргумент, его и выводит. И в что в фаерфоксе что в хроме выведет 'css'

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: а в "других консолях" это в каким, их много? и везде alert выводит три значения?

Comment: стоит добавить в вопрос ссылку на твой `repl`, чтобы можно было увидеть проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Консоль  - `console.log(value);`

А метод `alert(value);` показывает диалоговое окно с опциональным (необязательным) сообщением и кнопкой OK.

То есть **alert()** принимает какое-то значение и приводит его к строковому типу данных (что-то конкретное или единственное)ж

А **console.log()** - может  принимать множество значений и все будут выведены в консоль.

> .log() - это один из методов, так же есть множество других.

Comment: У меня в онлайн-консоле одинаковый результат и при alert и console.log(). Код одинаково отображается и при "const web = 'html'; console.log('css', web, 'js');" и при "const web = 'html'; alert('css', web, 'js');" в обоих случаях вывод будет одинаковый -  "css html js".  В случае с хромовской консолью у меня не работает console.log() и выводится только undefined при console.log(), а в случае alert выводится только первое написанное т.е. только "css".

Answer (score 0):

Функция `alert`, как и методы `console.*` предоставляются хост средой, и результат выполнения зависит от реализации.

Соответственно, нельзя сравнивать работу функций из разных хостов, в данном случае браузера и `replit`.

Для браузера `alert` принимает ровно один параметр - строку.
Какой `alert` реализован в `replit` - неизвестно.